# Angular JQuery DataTable, Delay search untill more than one character has been typed

Tags: jquery, search, datatables, angular6

```
data.compnent.ts:

getData() {
    this._dServices.downloadData().subscribe((value) => this.data = value);
    setTimeout(function () {
      const table: any = $('#myTable');
      this.dataTable = table.DataTable({
        'paging': true,
        'ordering': true,
        'info': true,
        'columnDefs': [ {
          'targets': 2,
          'sortable': false
        } ]
      });
    }, 800);
  }

data.compnent.html:



<br>
<br>

<div class="container container-fluid">

  <div class="">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" (click)="getData()" > Get Started </button>
    <br>
      <table datatable dtOptions="dtOptions" class=" table row-border" id="myTable" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Score </th>
          <th> News Title </th>
          <th> URL </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let a of data">
          <td>{{a.score}}</td>
          <td>{{a.title}}</td>
          <td>{{a.url}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Details ##

I want to work my app as search should perform until user enters more than one character can anyone provide me solution for it using jQuery DataTable Library.
Sorting and simple searching is working good.
solutions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no other option than reset the built-in event handlers and trigger your own :

```
$('.dataTables_filter input')
  .off('keyup.DT search.DT input.DT paste.DT cut.DT')
  .on('keyup.DT search.DT input.DT paste.DT cut.DT', function(e) {
    if (this.value.length>1) $.fn.dataTable.tables({ api: true }).search(this.value).draw()
  })
```

Do this *after* DT is initialized, for example in `initComplete` :

```
this.dataTable = table.DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    //insert above code here
   }
   ...
})
```

But since this is Angular and TS you may experience conflicts. There is no other workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Now Im having trouble getting the typed text in search field.
In your code this.value give error that  " Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' "

Comment: You *are* targeting `$('.dataTables_filter input')` and you are **not** using an arrow function??  And you are doing this inside a `initComplete` callback? Try with `$('.dataTables_filter input').val()` instead. It would work on a normal jQuery DataTables scenario and it seems odd `this` is of type `HTMLElement`, it should be a `HTMLInputElement`. Feels like you are doing something creative.

Answer (score 1):

Now Finally I have done this by using the logic:

```
$('.dataTables_filter input')
    .off('keyup.DT search.DT input.DT paste.DT cut.DT')
    .on('keyup.DT search.DT input.DT paste.DT cut.DT', function(e) {
      if ( (($('.dataTables_filter input').val())['length']) > 1) {
        $.fn['dataTable'].tables({ api: true }).search($('.dataTables_filter input').val()).draw();
      }
      if ( (($('.dataTables_filter input').val())['length']) < 1) {

        $.fn['dataTable'].tables({ api: true }).search('').draw();
      }
     });
```

Thanks for your help buddy !